# What is causing my drag and drop function to stutter with an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop an application that allows users to display multiple Youtube videos, with additional functionality including being able to drag and resize the videos however they'd like.

My drag seems to work as expected, until I add an iframe into the middle. Then, it begins to stutter and lag when I'm dragging the video container. Almost as if it's losing track of the pointer.

What could be causing this issue?

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("container"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  var dragHandles = elmnt.getElementsByClassName("drag-handle");

  // Assign drag functionality to each drag handle
  for (var i = 0; i < dragHandles.length; i++) {
    dragHandles[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      dragMouseDown(e, elmnt);
    });
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e, elmnt) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = throttle(function(e) {
      elementDrag(e, elmnt);
    }, 16); // Throttle to approximately 60 FPS
  }

  function elementDrag(e, elmnt) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }

  // Throttle function
  function throttle(func, limit) {
    let lastFunc;
    let lastRan;
    return function(...args) {
      const context = this;
      if (!lastRan) {
        func.apply(context, args);
        lastRan = Date.now();
      } else {
        clearTimeout(lastFunc);
        lastFunc = setTimeout(function() {
          if (Date.now() - lastRan >= limit) {
            func.apply(context, args);
            lastRan = Date.now();
          }
        }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  border: 1px solid #bcd8c1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.drag-handle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  color: #fff;
}

.video {
  width: 94%;
  height: 88%;
  background-color: rgb(145, 153, 150);
  margin: auto;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.drag-handle button {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06e1971d77.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="drag-handle">
      <button id="play-pause-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe src="https://iframetester.com/"></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div class="drag-handle"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in Chrome latest

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The HTML should be in the post?

Comment: @mplungjan I _can_ reproduce in the latest Chrome (on Mac) - when you move fast enough, and get your mouse cursor over a position where the iframe "previously" was, then it starts to stutter.

Comment: @RyanOliver Please leave the runnable version intact!

Comment: @CBroe I can shake it about like an angry terrier

Comment: @mplungjan interesting; but I suppose it might depend on more details than just browser and OS? Perhaps the frequency of mouse pointer coordinate updates is different, or something like that.

Comment: I'm running Windows 11 and don't notice any stuttering in Firefox, but dragging it does stutter a tiny bit in Chrome. Nothing too crazy, but enough to think that there's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It begins to "stutter", when I move the mouse fast enough, and get over the position where the iframe "previously" was.

Adding a class to the dragged element, that applies `pointer-events: none` to the iframe(s) within, appears to be able to mitigate the issue.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("container"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  var dragHandles = elmnt.getElementsByClassName("drag-handle");

  // Assign drag functionality to each drag handle
  for (var i = 0; i < dragHandles.length; i++) {
    dragHandles[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      dragMouseDown(e, elmnt);
    });
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e, elmnt) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    elmnt.classList.add('dragging'); /* add class here */
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = throttle(function(e) {
      elementDrag(e, elmnt);
    }, 16); // Throttle to approximately 60 FPS
  }

  function elementDrag(e, elmnt) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    elmnt.classList.remove('dragging'); /* remove class again when done dragging */
  }

  // Throttle function
  function throttle(func, limit) {
    let lastFunc;
    let lastRan;
    return function(...args) {
      const context = this;
      if (!lastRan) {
        func.apply(context, args);
        lastRan = Date.now();
      } else {
        clearTimeout(lastFunc);
        lastFunc = setTimeout(function() {
          if (Date.now() - lastRan >= limit) {
            func.apply(context, args);
            lastRan = Date.now();
          }
        }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan));
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  border: 1px solid #bcd8c1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.drag-handle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  color: #fff;
}

.video {
  width: 94%;
  height: 88%;
  background-color: rgb(145, 153, 150);
  margin: auto;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.drag-handle button {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  background-color: #bcd8c1;
  color: antiquewhite;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* make iframes in dragged container ignore pointer events */
#container.dragging iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06e1971d77.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="drag-handle">
      <button id="play-pause-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe src="https://iframetester.com/"></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div class="drag-handle"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue, thank you so much.

Comment: Slight issue with this, it prevents the user from clicking on the video so they can watch it. I'll attempt to remove the class after the drag movement is stopped.

Comment: I tried that already, in the `closeDragElement` function, is that not working?